# ¿Como escribo y leo campos y subcampos en Firebase | Google?

Tags: android, base-de-datos, firebase

Buenas, estoy intentando acceder a la base de datos que proporciona Google con Firebase, mi codigo resumido es simplemente esto.

```
FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
DatabaseReference myRef = 
    database.getReferenceFromUrl("https://pruebasfirebase-23d0d.firebaseio.com/");
```

De aquí en adelante no se como trabajar, quiero lograr algo de este estilo:

-Raiz
+SuperCampo
----SubCampo
----Subcampo
+SuperCampo
----SubCampo
----SubCampo

Lo que quiero saber es despues de obtener mi referencia de la base de datos con que metodos leer un par clave-valor (campo) y tambien como escribir, todo con su respectiva jerarquia, aunque creo que sabiendo como escribir y leer de la raíz ya me las arreglaría.

Comment: Creo que tienes que darte una vuelta por la documentación de firebase , todo eso sale ahí

Answer (score 0):

Asumiendo que tienes los permisos correctos de lectura/escritura(en las reglas de la base de datos de firebase) y que tienes vinculada ya la app en firebase con tu app en Android Studio (el archivo google-services.json):

Para leer:

1) Crear Referencia, 
`DatabaseReference mRootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();`

2) Hacer las "consulta" (por usar un termino parecido):

```
Query mConsulta = mRootRef
            .child("SuperCampo").child("SubCampo");
```

3) Establecer un listener que estará atento a los cambios cuando se agregan,cambian,borran,mueven,etc los datos.(solo incluyo el de agregado pero puedes implementar los otros métodos después)

```
ChildEventListener childEventListener = new ChildEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
            ClaseModelo mObjeto1 = dataSnapshot.getValue(ClaseModelo.class);

            String campo1 = mObjeto1.getCampo1();
            String campo2 = mObjeto1.getCampo2();

        }
}
```

En realidad te haría una sugerencia, por la referencia me parece que te estarías basando en documentación vieja de como se hacía antes. 
[Te sugiero seguir estas instrucciones que te permiten hacer lo que tu deseas.](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/start/)

Espero te sirva